# Warum »welchen« in »Welchen der vorgestellten Orte«?

Tags: grammatical-case, adjective-ending, interrogative

Ich hab den Satz

> Welchen der vorgestellten Orte würden sie gern besuchen?

gelesen. Kann mir bitte jemand erklären, warum ausgerechnet *welchen* mit der Endung *en* benutzt wird?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der zugrundeliegende Satz lautet:

> **Wen** würden sie gern besuchen?

Das Verb *besuchen* steht immer mit Akkusativ.

> **Welchen** würden sie gern besuchen?

ist ebenfalls Akkusativ, nur mit einem anderen Fragewort, das eine Auswahl einleitet. Nun wird es etwas komplizierter. Auswahlen stehen sehr häufig im Genitiv:

> Eine **der Möglichkeiten**.
>
> Zwei **der drei**.
>
> Welcher **der Orte**?

Die Alternativen mit Präposition

> Eine **aus den Möglichkeiten**.
>
> Eine **von den Möglichkeiten**.

kommen zwar umgangssprachlich auch vor, sind aber in der Schriftsprache verpönt.

Comment: Wenn ich es richtig sehe, sind die Auswahlen selbst immer (oder meist) im Genitiv ("Welcher **der** Orte ..."), während der gesamte Ausdruck in diesem Fall aber einen Akkusativ ("Welch**er** der Orte ...") darstellt.

Comment: In *Welch**er** der Orte* ist *welcher* aber Nominativ.

Comment: Natürlich. Ich habe mich vertippt. In der Frage hieß es "Welch**en**...".

Answer (score 1):

Zur Ergänzung hier Beispielsätze mit allen vier im Deutschen üblichen Fällen:

Nominativ:

> Welcher der vorgestellten Orte interessiert Sie?

Akkusativ:

> Welchen der vorgestellten Orte würden Sie gerne besuchen?

Dativ:

> Welchem der vorgestellten Orte würden Sie den Vorzug geben?

Genitiv:

> Welches der vorgestellten Orte nächtliche Ansicht ist Ihnen in Erinnerung?

Der Genitiv-Beispielsatz ist nun natürlich unrealistisch kompliziert. Hier eine Herleitung:

> Des Ortes schönste Ansicht
>
> Welches Ortes schönste Ansicht?
>
> Welches dieser Orte schönste Ansicht?
>
> Welches der vorgestellten Orte schönste Ansicht?